# Pass array literal to PostgreSQL function

Tags: php, sql, arrays, postgresql, parameter-passing

I have a Postgres function which contains a select statement. I need to add a condition using a passed in variable containing an array of string values.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_questions(vcode text)
  RETURN return_value as $f$
DECLARE vresult return_value;

BEGIN
--snip--

SELECT id, title, code
FROM questions WHERE code NOT IN (vcode);

--snip--
```

`questions` table:

```
id ,title, code
1, "title1", "qcode1"
2, "title2", "qcode2"
3, "title3", "qcode3"
4, "title4", "qcode4"
```

How should the `vcode` literal be formatted in PHP and what should be the syntax of the condition?

Using PostgreSQL 9.1.1, PHP 5.3.6, `pg_query_params`.

Comment: PostgreSQL and PHP versions? Are you using PDO or the `pg_` functions?

Comment: @CraigRinger I am using the pg_ functions.  pg_query_params($db, $SQL, $input)

Comment: @user2254435 Well, first, you're vulnerable to a major security hole, update. http://www.postgresql.org/support/security/faq/2013-04-04/

Answer (score 41, accepted):

SQL `NOT IN` works with *sets*. Since you are passing an *array*, use `<> ALL`.

You have to be careful not to involve any `NULL` values with such an expression, because `NULL <> anything` never evaluates to `TRUE` and therefore never qualifies in a `WHERE` clause.

Your function could look like this:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_questions(vcode text[])
  RETURNS TABLE(id int, title text, code text)
  LANGUAGE sql AS
$func$
SELECT q.id, q.title, q.code
FROM   questions q
WHERE  q.code <> ALL ($1);
$func$;
```

Call with [**array literal**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html#ARRAYS-INPUT):

```
SELECT * FROM get_questions('{qcode2, qcode2}');
```

Or with an [**array constructor**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ARRAY-CONSTRUCTORS)):

```
SELECT * FROM get_questions(ARRAY['qcode2', 'qcode2']);
```

Or you could use a `VARIADIC` parameter:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_questions(VARIADIC vcode text[]) ...
```

... and pass a *list* of values:

```
SELECT * FROM get_questions('qcode2', 'qcode2');
```

Details:

- [Return rows matching elements of input array in plpgsql function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17978310/select-rows-such-that-names-match-elements-of-input-array-for-pgsql-function/17978831#17978831)

#### Major points:

Using a simple SQL function since there is nothing in your question that would require the procedural elements of PL/pgSQL.

The input parameter is an array of text: `text[]`

To return multiple rows from your query use [`RETURNS TABLE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html) for the return type.

Referring to the in parameter with the positional parameter `$1` since referring by name was only introduced with version 9.2 for SQL functions (as opposed to plpgsql functions where this has been around for some versions now).

Table-qualify column names that would otherwise conflict with `OUT` parameters of the same name defined in the `RETURNS` clause.

#### `LEFT JOIN unnest($1)` / `IS NULL`

Faster for long arrays (> ~ 80 elements, it depends):

```sql
SELECT q.id, q.title, q.code
FROM   questions q
LEFT   JOIN unnest($1) c(code) USING (code)
WHERE  c.code IS NULL;
```

This variant (as opposed to the above) ignores NULL values in the input array.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Setting the IN column type to "text[]" was what I hadn't tried.  I thought I could just pass in an array of text values, but apparently not.

Comment: @user2254435: If it's easier for you to pass a comma-separated string as `text`, you can do that, and transform it to an array inside the function with [`string_to_array()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE). If your list gets long, performance will be better with `LEFT JOIN` / `IS NULL`. I added demo code to my answer.

Comment: You can use `WHERE q.code = ANY($1)` to get `q.code IN [...]` behaviour