# Return rows matching elements of input array in plpgsql function

Tags: arrays, postgresql, aggregate-functions, plpgsql, postgresql-9.2

I would like to create a PostgreSQL function that does something like the following:

```
CREATE FUNCTION avg_purchases( IN last_names text[] DEFAULT '{}' )
  RETURNS TABLE(last_name text[], avg_purchase_size double precision)
AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
  qry text;
BEGIN
qry := 'SELECT last_name, AVG(purchase_size) 
          FROM purchases
          WHERE last_name = ANY($1)
          GROUP BY last_name'
RETURN QUERY EXECUTE qry USING last_names;
END;
$BODY$
```

But I see two problems here:

1. It is not clear to me that array type is the most useful type of input.
2. This is currently returning zero rows when I do:

   ```
   SELECT avg_purchases($${'Brown','Smith','Jones'}$$);
   ```

What am I missing?

Comment: The use of text[] in the return type was a typo.  I leave it here because the accepted answer references that mistake.

Comment: It turns out that another big mistake was that the calling syntax (after correcting the problem according to the post from @Erwin) needed to be `SELECT avg_purchases($${Brown,Smith,Jones}$$)` or `SELECT avg_purchases('{Brown,Smith,Jones}')`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This works:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION avg_purchases(last_names text[] = '{}')
  RETURNS TABLE(last_name text, avg_purchase_size float8)
  LANGUAGE sql AS
$func$
SELECT last_name, avg(purchase_size)::float8
FROM   purchases
WHERE  last_name = ANY($1)
GROUP  BY last_name
$func$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM avg_purchases('{foo,Bar,baz,"}weird_name''$$"}');
```

Or (example with [dollar-quoting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING)):

```
SELECT * FROM avg_purchases($x${foo,Bar,baz,"}weird_name'$$"}$x$);
```

How to quote string literals:

- [Insert text with single quotes in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316953/insert-varchar-with-single-quotes-in-postgresql/12320729#12320729)

You don't need dynamic SQL here.

While you *can* wrap it into a plpgsql function (which may be useful), a simple SQL function is doing the basic job just fine.

You had **type mismatches**:

- The result of `avg()` may be `numeric` to hold a precise result. A cast to `float8` (alias for `double precision`) makes it work. For perfect precision, use `numeric` instead.
- The `OUT` parameter `last_name` must be `text` instead of `text[]`.

### `VARIADIC`

An array is a useful type of input. If it's easier for your client you can also use a [**`VARIADIC`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-VARIADIC-FUNCTIONS) input parameter that allows to pass the array as a *list of elements*:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION avg_purchases(VARIADIC last_names text[] = '{}')
  RETURNS TABLE(last_name text, avg_purchase_size float8)
  LANGUAGE sql AS
$func$
SELECT last_name, avg(purchase_size)::float8
FROM   purchases
JOIN  (SELECT unnest($1)) t(last_name) USING (last_name)
GROUP  BY 1
$func$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM avg_purchases('foo', 'Bar', 'baz', '"}weird_name''$$"}');
```

Or (with dollar-quoting):

```
SELECT * FROM avg_purchases('foo', 'Bar', 'baz', $y$'"}weird_name'$$"}$y$);
```

Stock Postgres only allows a **maximum of 100 elements**. This is determined at compile time by the [preset option](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-preset.html):

> `max_function_args (integer)`
>
> Reports the maximum number of function arguments. It is determined by the value of `FUNC_MAX_ARGS` when building the server. The default value is 100 arguments.

You can still call it with array notation when prefixed with the keyword `VARIADIC`:

```
SELECT * FROM avg_purchases(VARIADIC '{1,2,3, ... 99,100,101}');
```

For bigger arrays (100+), consider [`unnest()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) in a subquery and `JOIN` to it, tends to scale better:

- [Optimizing a Postgres query with a large IN](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/91539/3684)

Comment: Actually these will be big arrays in practice, so I am particularly keen on your *unnest()* suggestion.