# Pass multidimensional array as parameter to Postgresql function

Tags: arrays, postgresql, plpgsql, variadic-functions

I'm trying to maintain a Php application with a PostgreSQL database. At one point, a stored procedure is called, lets say `function_x` and inside `function_x`, `function_y` is called; `function_y` is passed a variable named `parameter_1`, and the definition of parameter_1 is:

```
parameter_1 numeric[][3] := {};
```

I'm trying to do a select function_y directly on the command line (or pgadmin) but I'm having problems passing an empty array into the function. according to the [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/xfunc-sql.html) you have to use `variadic` but so I tried:

```
select function_y(581, 'CPN-00000000001-0000', 'TPN-00000000001-0001', 100, 2013, variadic arr := array[]);
```

But I got this error:

```
ERROR:  cannot determine type of empty array
```

I tried different approaches but nothing works. How can I pass a multidimensional array as a parameter at a query?

Comment: Adding php tag would be wise.

Comment: I don't know... there's nothing of php on the question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You *can*, but you *do not have to* use [`VARIADIC` parameters](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-VARIADIC-FUNCTIONS) for array variables. You'd have to use it in the declaration of the function, not in the call, though.

2) Postgres array variables ignore dimensions in the definition. I quote [the manual here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/arrays.html#ARRAYS-DECLARATION):

> The current implementation does not enforce the declared number of
>   dimensions either. Arrays of a particular element type are all
>   considered to be of the same type, regardless of size or number of
>   dimensions. So, declaring the array size or number of dimensions in
>   `CREATE TABLE` is simply documentation; it does not affect run-time behavior.

3) This is invalid syntax:

```
parameter_1 numeric[][3] := {};
```

Single quotes are required:

```
parameter_1 numeric[][3] := '{}';
```

Which is effectively the same as

```
parameter_1 numeric[] := '{}';
```

More details, code examples and links in this closely related answer:
[Return rows matching elements of input array in plpgsql function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17978310/select-rows-such-that-names-match-elements-of-input-array-for-pgsql-function/17978831#17978831)

Comment: Isn't it usually better to use `array[...]` to avoid all the quoting nonsense that the string version (`'{...}'`) can lead to?

Comment: @muistooshort: It depends. If single quotes can be part of the literal, you could use dollar-quoting instead. Or use `quote_literal()`. In the case at had, for the empty array, my given answer should be simplest.