# Return multiple values and populate column in array like manner

Tags: sql, list, postgresql, distinct, aggregate-functions

I am using Postgres 9.3 on MacOSX.

I am wondering how I can return multiple values (depending on certain criterion) and use them to populate a column in a list/array like manner?

```
--DUMMY DATA

CREATE TABLE tbl (
   id VARCHAR(2) PRIMARY KEY
  ,name TEXT
  ,year_born NUMERIC
  ,nationality TEXT
);
INSERT INTO tbl(id, name, year_born, nationality)
VALUES ('A1','Bill',2001,'American')
      ,('B1','Anna',1997,'Swedish')
      ,('A2','Bill',1991,'American')
      ,('B2','Anna',2004,'Swedish')
      ,('B3','Anna',1989,'Swedish')
      ,('A3','Bill',1995,'American');
SELECT * FROM tbl;

id | name | year_born | nationality
---+------+-----------+------------
A1 | Bill |   2001    |  American
B1 | Anna |   1997    |  Swedish
A2 | Bill |   1991    |  American
B2 | Anna |   2004    |  Swedish
B3 | Anna |   1989    |  Swedish
A3 | Bill |   1995    |  American
```

I pool over column `name, nationality` by using `SELECT DISTINCT ON` clause as in the below code

```
CREATE TABLE another_tbl ( name TEXT, nationality TEXT, ids VARCHAR ); 

CREATE FUNCTION f1() RETURNS SETOF another_tbl AS
$$ SELECT DISTINCT ON (name, nationality) name, nationality, id
   FROM tbl
   GROUP BY name, nationality, ID;
$$ LANGUAGE sql

SELECT * FROM f1();

 name | nationality | ids 
------+-------------+-----
 Anna |  Swedish    | B1
 Bill |  American   | A1
```

So, here is the thing which I do not know how to achieve, but which I reckon is fairly easy. I want column `ids` to be populated by all the id's corresponding to the names in the `name` column as seen below.

Desired output:

```
 SELECT * FROM f1();

 name | nationality | ids 
------+-------------+-----
 Anna |  Swedish    | B1, B2, B3
 Bill |  American   | A1, A2, A3
```

**Update**

Found out about `ARRAY` which I use together with class `VARCHAR` for column `ids` in `another_tbl`. However, I get a mismatch call saying `Final statement returns character varying instead of`character varying[]`at column 3`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY` and the aggregate function [`string_agg()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-aggregate.html) if you want a text column as result.
Or [`array_agg()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-aggregate.html) to construct an array.
But drop the now redundant `DISTINCT ON`.

```
SELECT name, nationality, string_agg(id, ',') AS ids
FROM   tbl
GROUP  BY 1, 2
ORDER  BY 1, 2;
```

The `RETURNS` clause of your function definition has to match, like @ozczecho suggested:

```
CREATE FUNCTION f1()
  RETURNS TABLE(name text, nationality text, ids text) AS
                                              -- varchar[] for array_agg()
$func$
SELECT t.name, t.nationality, string_agg(t.id, ',') AS ids
FROM   tbl t
GROUP  BY 1, 2
ORDER  BY 1, 2;
$func$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

Comment: Cool, beats my answer..Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: I'm attempting to do the same, but using MS SQL. Is there any equivalent for string_agg() in MS SQL? Or another approach for MS SQL that would work to give similar results as this question asks?

Comment: @HammanSamuel: I asked this [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8109475/sql-server-collect-values-in-an-aggregation-temporarily-and-re-use-in-the-same) quite some time ago and got an excellent answer.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you should change:

```
RETURNS SETOF another_tbl
```

to:

```
RETURNS TABLE(name TEXT, nationality TEXT, ids VARCHAR[])
```

Comment: Thanks for commenting. Your suggestion gives the same mismatch error message however, since `RETURNS TABLE(name...)` in this case should be equivalent to `another_tbl`. And by default `VARCHAR[]` will set the array to one-dimension. In my case I do not know in advance how many dimensions the array needs to have. I think you can use `ARRAY` for that.

Comment: @jO.: Currently, there is only *one* array type for any given base type in Postgres, covering all dimensions. [Details in this related answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18707455/passing-multidimensional-array-as-parameter-postgresql-function/18709721#18709721)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it works using the `array_agg` function.

```
CREATE FUNCTION f1() RETURNS SETOF another_tbl AS
$$ SELECT DISTINCT ON (name, nationality) name, nationality, array_agg(id)
   FROM tbl
   GROUP BY name, nationality
$$ LANGUAGE sql

SELECT * FROM f();

name | nationality |    ids     
-----+-------------+-----------
Anna | Swedish     | {B1,B2,B3}
Bill | American    | {A1,A2,A3}
```

And after adding the function `array_to_string` to `array_agg(id)` we get the desired output

```
name | nationality |   ids    
-----+-------------+---------
Anna | Swedish     | B1,B2,B3
Bill | American    | A1,A2,A3
```