# FULL JOIN with =any doesn't use indexes

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, outer-join, postgresql-performance

Using Postgres 9.3.5, I can't seem to get a full outer join with an `=any` where-clause to use the relevant indexes.

A minimal example:

```
create table t1(i int primary key, j int);
create table t2(i int primary key, j int);

insert into t1 (select x,x from generate_series(1,1000000) x);
insert into t2 (select x,x from generate_series(1,1000000) x);

vacuum analyze;

explain analyze
    select * 
        from t1 full join t2 using(i) 
        where i =any (array[1,2]);
```

(In my real query, the array is a parameter and has variable length)

I get the following seq-scanning query plan:

```
 Hash Full Join  (cost=26925.00..66350.00 rows=10000 width=16) (actual time=178.308..1251.221 rows=2 loops=1)
   Hash Cond: (t1.i = t2.i)
   Filter: (COALESCE(t1.i, t2.i) = ANY ('{1,2}'::integer[]))
   Rows Removed by Filter: 999998
   ->  Seq Scan on t1  (cost=0.00..14425.00 rows=1000000 width=8) (actual time=0.011..59.463 rows=1000000 loops=1)
   ->  Hash  (cost=14425.00..14425.00 rows=1000000 width=8) (actual time=178.212..178.212 rows=1000000 loops=1)
         Buckets: 131072  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 39063kB
         ->  Seq Scan on t2  (cost=0.00..14425.00 rows=1000000 width=8) (actual time=0.012..57.751 rows=1000000 loops=1)
 Total runtime: 1255.734 ms
```

Unsuccessful things I tried:

- Use `i in (1,2)` or `i=1 or i=2` instead of `=any`
- `set enable_seqscan to f`

Simulating the full join with a left join and an anti-join works:

```
explain analyze 
    select * from
        (select i, t1.j, t2.j from t1 left join t2 using(i) 
         union all
         select i, null, j from t2 
             where not exists (select 1 from t1 where t1.i = t2.i)) sub
    where i =any (array[1,2]);


 Append  (cost=0.85..51.61 rows=3 width=12) (actual time=0.007..0.018 rows=2 loops=1)
   ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.85..29.79 rows=2 width=12) (actual time=0.007..0.010 rows=2 loops=1)
         ->  Index Scan using t1_pkey on t1  (cost=0.42..12.88 rows=2 width=8) (actual time=0.003..0.005 rows=2 loops=1)
               Index Cond: (i = ANY ('{1,2}'::integer[]))
         ->  Index Scan using t2_pkey on t2  (cost=0.42..8.44 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=1 loops=2)
               Index Cond: (t1.i = i)
   ->  Nested Loop Anti Join  (cost=0.85..21.79 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.008..0.008 rows=0 loops=1)
         ->  Index Scan using t2_pkey on t2 t2_1  (cost=0.42..12.88 rows=2 width=8) (actual time=0.001..0.002 rows=2 loops=1)
               Index Cond: (i = ANY ('{1,2}'::integer[]))
         ->  Index Only Scan using t1_pkey on t1 t1_1  (cost=0.42..4.44 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=1 loops=2)
               Index Cond: (i = t2_1.i)
               Heap Fetches: 0
 Total runtime: 0.065 ms
```

This approach would strongly complicate and add duplication to my real query, though. Is there any better way to get Postgres to use the indexes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pushing down the predicate into subqueries does the trick:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT * 
FROM      (SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE i = ANY ('{1,2}')) t1
FULL JOIN (SELECT * FROM t2 WHERE i = ANY ('{1,2}')) t2 USING (i);
```

> ```
> QUERY PLAN
> Merge Full Join (cost=0.58..25.26 rows=2 width=16) (actual time=0.084..0.100 rows=2 loops=1)
>   Merge Cond: (t1.i = t2.i)
>     -> Index Scan using t1_pkey on t1 (cost=0.29..12.62 rows=2 width=8) (actual time=0.044..0.048 rows=2 loops=1)
>          Index Cond: (i = ANY ('{1,2}'::integer[]))
>     -> Index Scan using t2_pkey on t2 (cost=0.29..12.62 rows=2 width=8) (actual time=0.028..0.033 rows=2 loops=1)
>          Index Cond: (i = ANY ('{1,2}'::integer[]))
> Total runtime: 0.256 ms
> ```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/22738/14) (with 100k rows).

Obviously, the query planner is not smart enough to conclude that indexes on the underlying tables can be used from a predicate on the column *after* the full join. This could be improved.

Can't test pg 9.4 right now. Maybe it *has* been improved.

BTW, most clients can't deal with multiple columns in the result using the same name (even though Postgres can do this). Your two instances of `j` would be a problem and you'd have to use at least one column alias, forcing you to list columns explicitly.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, in my case the join is part of the definition of a view, and the predicate is applied to the view by the application. I don't suppose there's any way to push down the predicate and keep using a view?

Comment: @FunctorSalad: I would consider a ***function*** then and pass the array items as parameter, possibly a `VARIADIC` function for convenience. [Details here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17978310/select-rows-such-that-names-match-elements-of-input-array-for-pgsql-function/17978831#17978831)