# Stored procedure syntax with IN condition

Tags: arrays, postgresql, stored-procedures, parameter-passing, plpgsql

(1)

```
=>CREATE TABLE T1(id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT);
CREATE TABLE
```

(2)

```
=>INSERT INTO T1
(name) VALUES
('Robert'),
('Simone');
INSERT 0 2
```

(3)

```
SELECT * FROM T1;
 id |  name  
----+--------
  1 | Robert
  2 | Simone
(2 rows)
```

(4)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_me(id_list BIGINT[]) 
RETURNS BOOLEAN AS
$$
BEGIN
  PERFORM * FROM T1 WHERE id IN ($1);
  IF FOUND THEN
    RETURN TRUE;
  ELSE
    RETURN FALSE;
  END IF;
END;
$$
  LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
CREATE FUNCTION
```

My problem is when calling the procedure. I'm not able to find an example on the net showing how to pass a list of values of type BIGINT (or integer, whatsoever).

I tried what follows without success (syntax errors):

First syntax:

```
eway=> SELECT * FROM test_me('{1,2}'::BIGINT[]);
ERROR:  operator does not exist: bigint = bigint[]
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM T1 WHERE id IN ($1)
                                  ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
QUERY:  SELECT * FROM T1 WHERE id IN ($1)
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function test_me(bigint[]) line 3 at PERFORM
```

Second syntax:

```
eway=> SELECT * FROM test_me('{1,2}');
ERROR:  operator does not exist: bigint = bigint[]
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM T1 WHERE id IN ($1)
                                  ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
QUERY:  SELECT * FROM T1 WHERE id IN ($1)
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function test_me(bigint[]) line 3 at PERFORM
```

Third syntax:

```
eway=> SELECT * FROM test_me(ARRAY [1,2]);
ERROR:  operator does not exist: bigint = bigint[]
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM T1 WHERE id IN ($1)
                                  ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
QUERY:  SELECT * FROM T1 WHERE id IN ($1)
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function test_me(bigint[]) line 3 at PERFORM
```

**Any clues about a working syntax?**

It's like the parser was trying to translate a BIGINT to BIGINT[] in the PEFORM REQUEST but it doesn't make any sense to me...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All your syntax variants to pass an array are *correct*.

- [Pass array literal to PostgreSQL function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17138792/pass-array-literal-to-postgresql-function/17139751#17139751)

The problem is with the expression inside the function. You can test with the [`ANY` construct](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-comparisons.html#AEN19712) like [@Mureinik provided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30352313/939860) or a number of other syntax variants. In any case run the test with an `EXISTS` expression:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_me(id_list bigint[]) 
  RETURNS bool AS
$func$
BEGIN
   IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM t1 WHERE id = ANY ($1)) THEN
      RETURN true;
   ELSE
      RETURN false;
   END IF;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql STABLE;
```

### Notes

- `EXISTS` is shortest and most efficient:

  - [PL/pgSQL checking if a row exists - SELECT INTO boolean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11892233/pl-pgsql-checking-if-a-row-exists-select-into-boolean/11892796#11892796)
- The `ANY` construct applied to arrays is only efficient with small arrays. For **longer arrays**, other syntax variants are faster. Like:

  ```
  IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM unnest($1) id JOIN t1 USING (id)) THEN ...
  ```

  - [How to do WHERE x IN (val1, val2,…) in plpgsql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/61552/3684)
- Don't quote the language name, it's an identifier, not a string: `LANGUAGE plpgsql`

#### Simple variant

While you are returning a `boolean` value, it can be even simpler. It's probably just for the demo, but as a proof of concept:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_me(id_list bigint[]) 
  RETURNS bool AS
$func$
SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM t1 WHERE id = ANY ($1))
$func$ LANGUAGE sql STABLE;
```

Same result.

Comment: Even though your solution is very good I'm wondering if I couldn't pass a list of scalar expressions to the stored procedure and hence use them directly with the "IN" option. Here (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/extend-type-system.html#AEN49791) they seem to say that a scalar is somehow converted to a kind of array "For each scalar type, a corresponding array type is automatically created". So I guess there is a way to pass from scalars to ARRAY and vice versa.

Comment: Or even pass directly a scalar list to the procedure somehow.

Comment: @Nitseg: You can use a `VARIADIC` parameter (as the last one) to pass an array as dynamic list of scalar values. That's sometimes handy for the call, but it's still a plain array inside the function: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19202832/pass-multiple-values-in-single-parameter/19204560#19204560.

Comment: @Nitseg: You can also pass any number of scalar parameters and use them in an `IN` expression by listing them separately, but that's very unwieldy (or impossible) for a dynamic number of elements. Only an option if you know the max. number of elements at the time you write the function. Also, [`IN (row of values)`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-comparisons.html#AEN19674) performs equally bad for long lists and is tricky with null handling, so there is really no good reason to force it.

Comment: OK, thanks a lot for answering my subsidiary questions. Scalars are to be used with static number of expressions, that makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to check if an item is in an array is with `= ANY`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_me(id_list BIGINT[]) 
RETURNS BOOLEAN AS
$$
BEGIN
  PERFORM * FROM T1 WHERE id = ANY ($1);
  IF FOUND THEN
    RETURN TRUE;
  ELSE
    RETURN FALSE;
  END IF;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```