# How to integrate a CASE construct with the VARIADIC keyword as input to format()

Tags: sql, postgresql, variadic, postgresql-11

How can I use `VARIADIC` to pass an array of arguments to the `FORMAT()` function depending on a `CASE` condition in PostgreSQL 11?

This, for instance, works:

```
SELECT FORMAT('Hi %s, I am %s', VARIADIC ARRAY['John', 'Paul']);
```

> Hi John, I am Paul

This also works:

```
SELECT FORMAT('Hello %s, I am %s.',
              CASE
                WHEN 1 = 1 THEN 'John'
                ELSE 'Mary'
              END,
             CASE
                WHEN 1 = 1 THEN 'Paul'
                ELSE 'Elli'
              END);
```

> Hello John, I am Paul.

This, however, doesn't:

```
SELECT FORMAT('Hello %s, I am %s.',
              CASE
                WHEN 1 = 1 THEN VARIADIC ARRAY['John', 'Paul']
                ELSE VARIADIC ARRAY['Mary', 'Elli']
              END);
```

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "VARIADIC"
> LINE 3:             WHEN 1 = 1 THEN VARIADIC ARRAY['John', 'Paul...

Theoretically it should work, and if it does it'll save me from repeating `CASE` as many times as the number of parameters I have to pass. I don't want to surround `FORMAT` with `CASE` because my string is huge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`VARIADIC` is a modifier for array input into functions. `format()` happens to use it. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER)

> The `concat`, `concat_ws` and `format` functions are `variadic`, so it
> is possible to pass the values to be concatenated or formatted as an
> array marked with the `VARIADIC` keyword (see [Section 38.5.5](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-VARIADIC-FUNCTIONS)).

The same is not true for a [`CASE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE) construct, which isn't even a *function* to begin with. There is still a simple solution:

```sql
SELECT format('Hello %s, I am %s.', VARIADIC  -- here!
              CASE
                WHEN true THEN ARRAY['John', 'Paul']
                ELSE ARRAY['Mary', 'Elli']
              END);
```

You just misplaced the keyword. `VARIADIC` is an *input* modifier. Not applicable to output.

#### Combine array and non-array parameters?

(Answer to question in the comment.)
It's not possible to pass individual strings *and* an array at the same time. Concatenate all arguments to a single array before passing in `VARIADIC` mode:

```sql
SELECT format E'Title: %s\nHi %s, I am %s.'::text, VARIADIC
'MyTitle'::text || ARRAY['John', 'Paul']);
```

Or put everything into an array to begin with, if you are in control of parameters. Demonstrating an array literal this time:

```sql
SELECT format(E'Title: %s\nHi %s, I am %s.'::text,  VARIADIC '{MyTitle, John, Paul}'::text[]);
```

Related:

- [Pass array literal to PostgreSQL function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17138792/pass-array-literal-to-postgresql-function/17139751#17139751)
- [Return rows matching elements of input array in plpgsql function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17978310/return-rows-matching-elements-of-input-array-in-plpgsql-function/17978831#17978831)

Comment: Thank you. Does one have to put all of the arguments inside one array now for `format()` to accept them? or can one pass some unconditional parameters to `format()` and pass only the conditional parameters in a `VARIADIC` `ARRAY`? This is giving an error `SELECT FORMAT(E'Title: %s\nHi %s, I am %s.'::text, 'MyTitle'::text, VARIADIC ARRAY['John', 'Paul']);`

Comment: That's it, I ended up making one `ARRAY` but wanted to make sure I am not missing anything. Thank you again!