# Pass array as parameter to return all rows matching elements

Tags: arrays, postgresql

I am using Postgres for my Javascript project and I have an array of id's. Is there a way to return all the rows and their corresponding data using each id in the array.

[image: Array of Id's]

I want to return all the rows that has the id that is in the array.

Comment: Please provide data as *text*. Never as image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of various ways: pass an array literal to the `= ANY` construct:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE id = ANY ('{46995, 54262, 73166}');
```

See:

- [Pass array literal to PostgreSQL function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17138792/pass-array-literal-to-postgresql-function/17139751#17139751)
- [IN vs ANY operator in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34627026/in-vs-any-operator-in-postgresql/34627688#34627688)