# Function using '= ALL ($1)' returning no values when multiple params passed

Tags: postgresql

```
CREATE FUNCTION test(VARIADIC arr text[]) 
RETURNS TABLE (data_time TIMESTAMPTZ, id text, data jsonb) 
    AS 'SELECT data_timestamp, key, value 
       FROM hit_count 
       CROSS JOIN jsonb_each(data) 
       WHERE key = ALL ($1)' 
LANGUAGE SQL;
```

If I call the function above with `select test('123')` it works fine. If I call it with `select test('123','234')` it returns nothing ie

```
test 
------
(0 rows)
```

However if I define it as

```
CREATE FUNCTION test(VARIADIC arr text[]) 
RETURNS TABLE (data_time TIMESTAMPTZ, id text, data jsonb) 
    AS 'SELECT data_timestamp, key, value 
        FROM hit_count 
        CROSS JOIN jsonb_each(data) 
        WHERE key != ALL ($1)' 
LANGUAGE SQL;
```

then the function returns all the data but those that fit the condition

Any ideas??

Comment: I don't know how Postgres handles parameters but perhaps you just want `in ($1)`?

Comment: @shawnt00 thats a no go. I tried it... also the last comment on this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17138792/pass-array-literal-to-postgresql-function suggest that the operator use is correct. So Im not sure

`ERROR:  operator does not exist: text = text[]
LINE 1: ...CROSS JOIN jsonb_each(data) WHERE key IN ($1)' L...`

Comment: @shawnt00 I id'd the problem. Answer below. Ty for your time

Comment: Makes sense. I should have even suggested that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ALL was used as opposed to ANY the corrected function looks like this

```
CREATE FUNCTION test(VARIADIC arr text[]) 
RETURNS TABLE (data_time TIMESTAMPTZ, id text, data jsonb) 
    AS 'SELECT data_timestamp, key, value 
        FROM hit_count 
        CROSS JOIN jsonb_each(data) 
        WHERE key = ANY ($1)' 
LANGUAGE SQL;
```